# What species of tree is this?

Tags: identification

Can someone tell me what species of tree this is?
I found it growing in a garden in Southern Sweden. It had long, thin twigs hanging from the branches, at the end of which were attached seed pods. 
The tree grew like a creeper, clinging and curling itself around nearby objects.

More detailed pictures can be provided at request if necessary for identification.

[image: Unknown tree]

[image: Seed pod of unknown tree]

Comment: It isn't a tree, from your description, it's a twining climber - there are quite a few which produce long seed pods like this (including wisteria). The leaves in the image are quite wilted and  difficult  to identify; a photo of the plant in situ would be useful, particularly in regard to scale of the pods, as well as a close up of healthier leaves, though I'm guessing, at this time of year, there may not be any leaves left by now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your photos are a bit blurry, together with the description it seems you are looking at a [wisteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wisteria).

Wisterias are often planted for their decorative inflorescence in spring, when the whole plant can seem covered in blue - which is reflected in names like “Blåregn“ (Swedish) and “Blauregen” (German), meaning “blue rain”.

Comment: I don't think its Wisteria - the seeds from that are a solid, dark brown/black colour, without the freckled appearance these have...

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Stephie on this as Wisteria. Here is a [photo from Vilmorin] (http://www.vilmorin-tree-seeds.com/images/documents/images/wisteria_sinensis.jpg) that shows some freckling. The photo in the question shows seeds still attached to the pod which indicates not yet in a dried down condition which may influence the coloring of the freckles.